# Python function that takes one compulsory argument from two choices

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function:

```
def delete(title=None, pageid=None):
    # Deletes the page given, either by its title or ID
    ...
    pass
```

However, my intention is for the function to take only one argument (either `title` OR `pageid`). For example, `delete(title="MyPage")` or `delete(pageid=53342)` are valid, while `delete(title="MyPage", pageid=53342)`, is not. Zero arguments can not be passed. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `if title is not None and pageid is not None: raise ValueError` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Python syntax that'll let you define exclusive-or arguments, no. You'd have to explicitly raise an exception is both or none are specified:

```
if (title and pageid) or not (title or pageid):
    raise ValueError('Can only delete by title OR pageid')
```

The full expression can become a little tedious, especially if `title` or `pageid` could be set to `0` or another falsey value that is valid, so you could capture the above in a utility function:

```py
from typing import Any

def exclusive_or(left: Any, right: Any) -> bool:
    """Test if either left or right is true, but not both"""
    return (left or right) and not (left and right)
```

Note that this is the inverse test of what you needed for the `if` test, so don't forget to add `not`:

```
if not exclusive_or(title, pageid):
    # ...
```

which is a lot easier to use when having to test for `not None`:

```
if not exclusive_or(title is not None, pageid is not None):
    # ...
```

Note that I used [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to add information to the function for type checkers and IDEs to see what kind of arguments the function takes or what the return value type is.

With type hints, you can also mark up your original function and tell *those tools* that your function only takes one or the other argument, by using [`@overload`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading):

```py
@overload
def delete(title: str) -> None: ...

@overload
def delete(pageid: int) -> None: ...

def delete(title: Optional[str] = None, pageid: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
    """Deletes the page given, either by its title or ID"""
    ...
    pass
```

In an IDE like PyCharm or Visual Studio Code (with the Pylance extension installed) would show you real-time information about the function as you type:

[image: Screenshot of a snippet of code in Visual Studio Code reading "delete()', with a tooltip showing "(title: str) -> None" and the documentation string for the delete function, together with a counter indicating this is one of two possible completions for this function]

[image: Another screenshot of the same snippet of code, this time with the tooltip changed to show "(pageid: int) -> None", with the counter indicating that this is the second of two possible completions]

This kind of tool integration would make it easier to use your function without triggering an exception.

Comment: I was thinking about this... Is this the only solution?

Comment: @TerryA: you'll have to explicitly raise an exception, yes. There is no syntax that tells Python to check this for you.

Comment: This will fail the case if pageid = 0 is given.
In Python, you have to be careful about discening 0 and None, cause both of them is considered as False in boolean way.

Comment: @heyzude: sure, that depends on the exact range of values that are acceptable for those variables. If you use `None` to mean 'not set', then use `(title is not None and pageid is not None) or not (title is not None or pageid is not None)`. If `None` is an acceptable value too, use a different sentinel value to test against, like `_sentinel = object()`, and `(title is not _sentinel and `, at which point a utility function might be needed..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to do this in the function signature itself. However, you could always have a check inside your function to see if both arguments are set

```
def delete(title=None, pageid=None):
# Deletes the page given, either by its title or ID
    if title and pageid:
        # throw error or return an error value
pass
```

Arguably a better way of doing it would be to define 2 methods that call the delete method

```
def delete_by_title(title):
    delete(title=title)

def delete_by_id(id):
    delete(pageid=id)
```

The second method won't stop people calling the delete function directly, so if that's really important to you I'd advise having it throw an exception as per my first example, or else a combination of the 2.

Comment: I like your second approach

Answer (score 0):

If both arguments can have any value, including `None`, then the solution is to use a sentinel object for them. Then you can calculate a sum over the  number of arguments that are set to non-default value:

```
NOT_SET = object()
def delete(title=NOT_SET, pageid=NOT_SET):
    if sum(i is not NOT_SET for i in [title, page_id]) != 1:
        raise ValueError('Can set only one of these')
```

This pattern is easily expandable to more arguments as well.